# How to download ISO files from IBM's download site? Browsers, FTP and WinSCP do not work

Tags: ftp, download, iso-image, winscp, ibm-server

On this page, [www.ibm.com/support/pages/vmware-vsphere-esxi-41-u3-hypervisor-ibm-customization-v10-ibm-systems-and-lenovo-x86-servers](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/vmware-vsphere-esxi-41-u3-hypervisor-ibm-customization-v10-ibm-systems-and-lenovo-x86-servers), I am trying to download `ibm_sw_hyper_800380v1_vmwaresx4_32-64.iso`.  The download is not working.  I have used FTP from a command line (Windows 10) and I have used WinSCP.  Nothing works.  How do I download this file?

The attempt to download the file using WinSCP created a log file over 200K lines long.  The relevant entries (I assume) are:

```
. 2021-03-30 17:22:31.253 Copying 1 files/directories to local directory "E:\Temp\" - total size: 0
. 2021-03-30 17:22:31.253   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: Yes; Mask: *.*
. 2021-03-30 17:22:31.253   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2021-03-30 17:22:31.253   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2021-03-30 17:22:31.253 File: '/ecc/sar/CMA/XSA/ibm_sw_hyper_800380v1_vmwaresx4_32-64.iso' [2016-03-07T08:00:00.000Z] [0] - Link to: 'ibm_sw_hyper_800380v1_vmwaresx4_32-64.iso' [n/a] [0]
. 2021-03-30 17:22:31.254 Skipping symlink to directory "/ecc/sar/CMA/XSA/ibm_sw_hyper_800380v1_vmwaresx4_32-64.iso".
. 2021-03-30 17:22:32.625 Copying finished: Transferred: 0, Elapsed: 0:00:01, CPS: 0/s
. 2021-03-30 17:22:32.888 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
```

Comment: There is an icon (down arrow icon) to the left of the file. It is working fine in my Linux system here, but does not work in Windows

Comment: Windows (Chrome, Chromium Edge) wants to "pick an app" which is incorrect. As I noted I, can do it with Linux. Spin up a Kali machine in Hyper-V, download the file and then map a folder in Windows 10 and transfer it over.That may work.

Comment: I did this in Kali in VMware and just know was able to initiate a download in Kali in Hyper-V on another machine. This seems to be the best way forward.

Comment: @john I'll try it in Linux Mint first, since I can spin that up in 2 seconds.

Comment: @John Forgot to mention, I also got the weird "Pick an app" message.  Your suggestion to try a Linux machine was good, but what I wound up doing was just switching to my Mac VM and trying it there.  Similar to Windows, the Mac wanted to open Finder when I attempted the download.  I said ok, Finder opened and the file downloaded!  If you post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thx.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you . Thank you!

Comment: What country are you in? Why does this link not work for you two on Windows? On macOS I am having no issues in multiple browsers: Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc… I can even do a `curl -O ftp://download2.boulder.ibm.com/ecc/sar/CMA/XSA/ibm_sw_hyper_800380v1_vmwaresx4_32-64.iso` from the Terminal and it works. There is no reason to spin up a VM to download a file like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows (Chrome, Chromium Edge) wants to "pick an app" which is incorrect.

I can download the file with Linux.

Spin up a Kali machine in Hyper-V, download the file and then map a folder in Windows 10 and transfer it over.I did this in Kali in Hyper-V on another machine and that works.

This seems to be the best way forward.

Answer (score 1):

The `ibm_sw_hyper_800380v1_vmwaresx4_32-64.iso` is a link to `04pc2/3/ibm_sw_hyper_800380v1_vmwaresx4_32-64.iso`. The current version of WinSCP does not follow links with FTP protocol. But you can just directly use a URL to the target file:

ftp://download2.boulder.ibm.com/ecc/sar/CMA/XSA/04pc2/3/ibm_sw_hyper_800380v1_vmwaresx4_32-64.iso

[Paste the URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_download#url) to your browser.

---

The next version of WinSCP will be able to handle the URL with link directly:
https://winscp.net/tracker/1973

Comment: The next version of WinSCP will be able to handle the URL with link directly:  
https://winscp.net/tracker/1973